# How to instantiate a generic class based on class parameters in Java

Tags: java

How do I instantiate a new generic class based on class parameters?
My main class looks as follows:

```
public class ServiceTransformer<SERVICE_I, SERVICE_O> extends Loggable {

private Class<SERVICE_I> serviceInputClass;
private Class<SERVICE_O> serviceOutputClass;

public ServiceTransformer(Logger logger, String inputXslt, String outputXslt, String appRoot) {
    try {
        serviceInputClass = (Class<SERVICE_I>) getGenericTypeClass(0);
        serviceOutputClass = (Class<SERVICE_O>) getGenericTypeClass(1);
    } catch (BadConfigurationException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("@@@ ConfigBase() Constructor Exception => ", ex);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("@@@ ConfigBase() Constructor Exception => ", ex);
    }
}

private Type getGenericTypeClass(int index) {
    try {
        return ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[index];
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("@@@ getGenericTypeClass() Exception => ", ex);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And I instantiate a new `ServiceTransformer` class as follows:

```
ServiceTransformer<ReactivatePrepaidSubscriberInput, ReactivatePrepaidSubcriberOutput> service = 
                new ServiceTransformer<ReactivatePrepaidSubscriberInput, ReactivatePrepaidSubcriberOutput>(
                        LOGGER, inputFile, outputFile, APPROOT);
```

The error that I am currently getting is `java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`

No idea where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only possible to get the generic type arguments from the superclass, just as you are doing it:

`return ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()`

But your `ServiceTransformer` does not extend a generic class, only `Loggable`, which is not generic, hence cannot be cast to `ParameterizedType`.

The trick you could do would be to instantiate an anonymous subclass of `ServiceTransformer`:

```
new ServiceTransformer<In, Out>(LOGGER, inputFile, outputFile, APPROOT) {};
```

(note the `{}` at the end)

That would allow access to the generic type arguments of the superclass - this time the superclass is the `ServiceTransformer` class itself.

However, note that every time you use this anonymous class construct, a new class is created by the compiler which may affect the performance of your application.

If you are often using a fixed set of `<In, Out>` types, create a proper top-level named subclass for it and reuse that, as suggested in other answers. Eg.

```
class StringIntTransformer extends ServiceTransformer<String, Integer>
```

if you use the  combination often.

Comment: That solved it! What would you suggest for disposing of these newly created anonymous classes?

Comment: That's not possible - they are generated during compilation (you'll see them as `SurroundingClass$1.class`, `SurroundingClass$2.class`, etc.) and once they are loaded, they stay in memory. But I wouldn't worry about it, unless you are creating thousands of those anonymous classes. If you are often using a fixed set of `<In, Out>` types, create a proper top-level named subclass for it and reuse that, as suggested in other answers. Eg. `class StringIntTransformer extends ServiceTransformer<String, Integer>` if you use the <String, Integer> combination often.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that generic type arguments can be retrieved only from an inheritance context, you can see it clearly from the method name:

```
getGenericSuperclass()
```

This means that you need to instantiate a subtype of `ServiceTransformer<I,O>` to be able to query for the type arguments.

This can be done in two ways, you can have a custom real type as

```
public static class MyServiceTransformer extends ServiceTransformer<ReactivatePrepaidSubscriberInput,ReactivatePrepaidSubcriberOutput>
{
  MyServiceTransformer()
  {
    super(...);
  }
}
```

Or you can define it anonymously:

```
new ServiceTransformer<ReactivatePrepaidSubscriberInput, ReactivatePrepaidSubcriberOutput>(....){}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a deeper inheritance.

```
public abstract class AbstractServiceTransformer<SERVICE_I, SERVICE_O> extends Loggable {

private Class<SERVICE_I> serviceInputClass;
private Class<SERVICE_O> serviceOutputClass;

public ServiceTransformer(Logger logger, String inputXslt, String outputXslt, String appRoot) {
        serviceInputClass = TypeUtils.getParametrizedType(this.getClass(),0)
        serviceOutputClass = TypeUtils.getParametrizedType(this.getClass(),1)
}

...
}
```

Then here your actual implementation.

```
public class ServiceTransformer extends AbstractServiceTransformer<Service1, Service2> {
    ...
}
```

After that you can read class of type parameters like this.

```
public final class TypeUtils {

    /**
     * Returns parameterized type as a Class.
     */
    public static <T> Class<T> getParametrizedType(Class<?> baseClass, int index) {
        final Type genericSuperClass = baseClass.getGenericSuperclass();

        if (!(genericSuperClass instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your super class need to have a parameterized type");
        }

        final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperClass;
        final Type[] types = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();

        if (types[index] instanceof Class<?>) {
            return (Class<T>) types[index];
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter type is mismatched");
        }

    }

}
```